# Get fixedDelay value inside @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to get the value of `fixedDelay` inside of the method being executed?

Does something like this exist:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 86400000) //one day
public void sendEmails() {
    System.out.println(TaskExecutor.getCurrentFixedDelay()); // (would print 86400000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class AnnotationParameter {

        @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 86400000) //one day
        public void sendEmails() throws NoSuchMethodException
        {
            Method method = AnnotationParameter.class.getDeclaredMethod
                ("sendEmails");
            Scheduled annotation = method.getAnnotation(Scheduled.class);
            long fixedDelay = annotation.fixedDelay();
            System.out.println(fixedDelay); // (would print 86400000)
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException
        {
            new AnnotationParameter().sendEmails();
        }
    }
```